# Using media queries with jQuery

Tags: jquery, media-queries

I am using jQuery for the first time and I have a few div animations that work great. However, on a 720 p screen the events fire at the wrong time, since there are less pixels and the event is triggered via pixels scrolled. I tried adapting my code with media queries, but then it just broke.

Can anyone help?

HTML sample:

```
<div class="textone">This is some text!</div>
```

CSS:

```
.textone {
  position:fixed;
  top:8%;
  left:-1000px;
  z-index:4;
  width:19%;
  background:#99cc00;
  border-radius:3px;
  opacity:0.9;
  font-size:1.3em;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  padding:1% 0.1% 1% 3.3%;
}
```

JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    //THIS MAKES THE SLIDEY THINGS SLIDE
    //textone
    if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 1599px)").matches) {
        // window width is under 1599px
        jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
            if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 333 && jQuery(this).scrollTop() < 1667) {
                jQuery('.textone').stop().animate({ left: '0px' });
            } else {
                jQuery('.textone').stop().animate({ left: '-500px' });
            }
        });
    } else {
        // window width is greater than 1599px
        jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
            if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 500 && jQuery(this).scrollTop() < 2500) {
                jQuery('.textone').stop().animate({ left: '0px' });
            } else {
                jQuery('.textone').stop().animate({ left: '-500px' });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: The code seems to work? http://jsfiddle.net/T7qA9/ (scroll down in the "Result" panel) What is "breaking" for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should determine the value where you want your `.textone` to appear programmatically, not hardcoded.

You can determine the "*333*" and "*1667*" for example from the offsetTop of some element on your page or by a percent of the height of your page.

You can probably use jQuerys `.offset().top` to get the offset of your elemenet from the top of the window.